# Combining results in a mysql-query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql-table (lets call it *table*) where I store points scored in a game.

```
| ID | SCORE |
|----|-------|
|1   |10     |
|2   |8      |
|3   |15     |
|4   |9      |
```

What I'm wondering if there is a neat way to get one row containing the last score (the one with the
highest ID) and the highest score?

Currently I'm doing

```
SELECT
    score AS last_score,
    (SELECT MAX(score) FROM table) AS best_score
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

which gives me exactly what I want:

```
|last_score|best_score|
|----------|----------|
|9         |15        |
```

But performance wise I wonder if it's better not to have two `select`:s

I would prefer to do something in the lines of

```
SELECT
    score AS last_score,
    MAX(score) AS best_score
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

which gives me the best score, but not the latest.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let's not call it table :-(

Comment: I would use UNION, which will give you a one-column result.

Comment: @Strawberry You mean the result will be like `first row = latest score` and `second row = best score` or something in that direction?

Comment: Yep, something like that - probably with a column to identify which is which

Answer (score 0):

select (SELECT score
from purchase ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) as last_score, (SELECT MAX(score) as max_score
from purchase) as max_score

Comment: I'm sorry, you must've posted your answer on the wrong page. This isn't even close to what I was asking for.

Comment: I updated my answer sorry, missing last_score

Comment: Now it makes more sense, thanks. But it's still more or less exactly what I wrote in my question (se below "Currently I'm doing")